# Java how to calculate time differences

Tags: java, time

How can I calculate the time differences in 24 hour if the user input is 2255 and 2305 the output should be 10 minutes. I got an idea is to separate the input to 2 parts, 2 digits and 2 digits. the first 2 digits is the hour, times it to 60 to make it to minutes. Then plus it with the second 2 digits and then calculate the differences. I dont want use any Date Calendar data type or API to solve it. Thanks

Comment: @user236501 - I rolled back your question, as there was an answer posted. This will allow others with your question to find the answer. ("Sorry please ignore" helps no one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get first 2 digit without using String chartAt.

Highest two digits: number / 100
Lowest two digist: number % 100

But what would you do if user enter 3:05 or 3-05? I think it's problem of usability. Best solution is making UI definitely understandable for user. For example you can use separate fields for hours and minutes.

Comment: how about if start time is 0025and endTime is 0035, which mean it is already next day

Comment: Do you mean start time is 0035 and end is 0025? So you need to normailze negative result (24 * 60 + (25 - 35)). But if end time is two days before start? As I already said I think it's usability problem. Developer should make controls for input with exact meaning of inputting values.

Answer (score 6):

```
    String time1 = "2255";
    String time2 = "2305";

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
    Date date1 = format.parse(time1);
    Date date2 = format.parse(time2);
    long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
```

difference is in millis you can convert it to any unit or you can use `DurationFormatUtils` from apache-commons to pretty format it.

```
System.out.println("Duration: "+DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(difference, "HH:mm"));
```

apache commons has really nice utility functions, [apache-commons (lang)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)