# How can I perform arithmetic operation with dates in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate time difference in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927856/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-java)

Actually I want to subtract two dates in Java.  I tried a lot but can't succeed.  So anyone please help me.

```
Date dtStartDate=pCycMan.getStartDate();

Date dtEndDate=pCycMan.getEndDate();
```

How can I subtract these two Dates?

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
long msDiff = dtEndDate.getTime() - dtStartDate.getTime()
```

`msDiff` now holds the number of milliseconds difference between the two dates.  Feel free to use the division and mod operators to convert to other units.

Comment: As others have noted, for anything more complex than this, Joda Time is definitely the way to go.

Comment: but i want the result like 20-jun-2011 - 1-june-2011=28

Comment: @Anshuman, I have no idea how June 20th minus June 1st would equal 28.  What units are you looking for?  Seems to me it would equal 19 days.  To get the number of days just use the code in my answer and then do `msDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)`.

Comment: hi Mike i have done it like this but it will give me the result in negative   long lDiffFromToday = currentDate.getTime()-dtSelDate.getTime();lDiffFromToday=lDiffFromToday/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

Answer (score 6):

> ***how can i subtract these two Dates?***

You can get the difference in milliseconds like this:

```
dtEndDate.getTime() - dtStartDate.getTime()
```

([`getTime`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.)

However, for this type of date arithmetics the [Joda time library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), which has proper classes for time durations (`Duration`) is probably a better option.

Comment: I said use .getTime but +1 for joda

Answer (score 1):

To substract to dates you can get them both as longs `getTime()` and subtract the values that are returned.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class.

Usage:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(dtStartDate);
int date = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); //int represents the year of the date
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); // int represents dayOfWeek as defined in link.
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) objects from those Dates and then use the add() method (which can be used to subtrade dates too).

Comment: can you please show me with an examples

Answer (score 0):

There is a framework to work with the date in java...
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html
take a look, i'm sure that it can help you

Comment: seems to be a bit of overkill for simple mathematics

Comment: You need something like this http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Days.html#minus(org.joda.time.Days) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
long diffInMillis = dtEndDate.getTimeInMillis() -  dtStartDate.getTimeInMillis();
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what do you want. To get difference in milliseconds say `dtStartDate.getTime() - dtEndDate.getTime()`.

To get difference in days, hours etc use Calendar class (methods like after, before, compareTo, roll may help).

Comment: actually i want the result in days so how that can be done

Comment: As in difference in dates? or as it terms of time-units? If the latter, you simply divide by `24*60*60*1000.0`.

Comment: can you please help me with examples