# How to determine if 48 hours has passed from a specific time?

Tags: java, time

I looking to check and see if 48 hours has pasted from a specific time? 
I am using this date time format (yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss) Is there any java function for this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Libraries like Joda-Time?  Calculating elapsed milliseconds between dates?

Comment: Convert both time strings to timestamps and check that they are more than `48 * 3600 * 1000` milliseconds apart.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate time difference in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927856/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating the Difference Between Two Java Date Instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

Answer (score 10):

Sure. <s>I would strongly advice you to pick up [Joda DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html)</s>. As @Basil Bourque put it in a comment, Joda is now in maintenance mode and since Java 8 you should use the java.time methods.

Current suggested code that's not library dependent and is more clear on what it does:

```
// How to use Java 8's time utils to calculate hours between two dates
LocalDateTime dateTimeA = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 9, 28, 12, 50, 55, 999);
LocalDateTime dateTimeB = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 9, 30, 12, 50, 59, 851);
long hours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(dateTimeA, dateTimeB);
System.out.println(hours);
```

Original suggested code (also not library dependent):

```
// pseudo-code
DateTime a = new DateTime("old time");
DateTime b = new DateTime(" now    ");

// get hours
double hours = (a.getMillis() - b.getMillis()) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
if(hours>48) ...
```

Comment: I agree using Joda DateTime is the best; otherwise you can use the native Calendar instead (but Joda DateTime is simpler).

Comment: FYI, the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to the java.time classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque thks for the update. I've edited answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to accomplish this by using a JodaTime Library in my project. I came out with this code.

```
String datetime1 = "2012/08/24 05:22:34";
String datetime2 = "2012/08/24 05:23:28";

DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTime time1 = format.parseDateTime(datetime1);
DateTime time2 = format.parseDateTime(datetime2);
Minutes Interval = Minutes.minutesBetween(time1, time2);
Minutes minInterval = Minutes.minutes(20);

if(Interval.isGreaterThan(minInterval)){
  return true;
}
else{
  return false;
}
```

This will check if the Time Interval between datetime1 and datetime2 is GreaterThan 20 Minutes. Change the property to Days. It will be easier for you now. This will return false.

Answer (score 4):

You can add 48 hours to a given date, and then if the result is earlier than your starting date, you know you're past 48 hours.

```
Date dateInQuestion = getDateInQuestion();

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dateInQuestion);
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 48);
Date futureDate = cal.getTime();

if (dateInQuestion.after(futureDate)) {
  // Then more than 48 hours have passed since the date in question
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Date twoDaysAgo = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2);
Date parsedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("y/M/d h:m:s").parse(myDateString);
boolean hasTimePasssed = parsedDate.before(twoDaysAgo);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to handle special cases, you can use the .before() function and make up a date object to represent 48 hours ago:

```
long millisIn48Hours = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 48;
Date timestamp = new Date(0);//use the date you have, parse it using SimpleDateFormat if needed.
Date hours48ago = new Date(new Date().getTime() - millisIn48Hours);

if (timestamp.before(hours48ago)) {
    //48 hours has passed.
}
```

EDIT: I wouldn't add a library dependency for something so simple, but if you're going to use JodaTime, I would use their convenience methods rather than calculate the time offset as in the other answer:

```
DateTime original = new DateTime("your original date object");
DateTime now = new DateTime();
DateTime minus48 = now.minusHours(48);

if (original.isBefore(minus48)) {
    //48 hours has elapsed. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
 DateTime specificDate = new DateTime(" some specific date");
 DateTime now = new DateTime();

 if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(now.getMillis() - specificDate.getMillis()) > 48) {
    //Do something
  }
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **Joda DateTime**

If you want to check if say one date is in between another time frame, say is `date1` 4hrs in between `date2`, joda has different classes just for those scenarios you can use:

```
Hours h = Hours.hoursBetween(date1, date2);
Days s = Days.daysBetween(date1, date2);
Months m = Months.monthsBetween(date1,date2);
```

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseSingleFieldPeriod.html

Comment: FYI, the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes.

Answer (score 0):

The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes.

Parse your string input of format `yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss`. That is nearly in standard ISO 8601 format. Adjust to comply.

```
String input = "2017/01/23 12:34:56".replace( "/" , "-" ).replace( " " , "T" ).concat( "Z" ) ;
```

If at all possible, use the standard formats rather than invent your own when exchanging date-time values as text. The java.time classes use the standard formats by default when parsing and generating strings.

Parse as a value in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

Get current moment.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

Compare to a span of time of 48 hours.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofHours( 48 ) ;
if ( instant.plus( d ).isBefore( now ) ) { … }
```