# Java converting string, having millisecond to date object

Tags: java, string, date

I have 2 Strings

- 2012-06-25 15:02:22.948
- +0530

I need a new string which adds the 5:30 to the time in the first string.

I thought I can do this by converting both strings to date objects and then adding. But i dont know how to do it, as when i use

yyyy MM dd hh:mm:ss as the date format for the first string, I get an error.

Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is here: [How to calculate time difference in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927856/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-java)

Comment: But i am not able to parse my string properly to a date object. I think its because of the 22.948, the decimal point

Comment: they are milliseconds...you need to use yyyy MM dd hh:mm:ss.SSS as format

Comment: The previous comment is a good way to start. Also you get an error because your first string is in "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS" format, not the one you provided.

Comment: Also your second string seems to represent timezone...this specifies IST timezone..I hope that clears you a way to get desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge both you string String1+string2 and can use format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` to parse the date. You can see more documentation  [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 3):

The format of the string `2012-06-25 15:02:22.948` is not `yyyy MM dd hh:mm:ss`, so it's not surprising that you get "an error" (what error is it? the more specific you are, the better people can help you!).

Try `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`. See the [API documentation of `SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to understand the exact syntax of the format string.

Note: Upper and lower case is important in the format string. `hh` means 12-hour clock, `HH` means 24-hour clock. If you use `hh`, parsing `15` for the hours won't work. You also didn't include the milliseconds `SSS` in the format string.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an exception because the your date format String is wrong. You're giving a date string on the form

```
"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S"
```

See [SimpleDateFormat javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
    Date date = format.parse("2012-06-25 15:02:22.948");
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());

    int time = Integer.parseInt("0530");
    int hour = time / 100;
    int minute = time % 100;

    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

    String newDateInString = format.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct but outdated.

## java.time

The old date-time classes (java.util.Date/.Calendar etc.) bundled with the earliest versions of Java are now legacy.

Those old classes have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

### `LocalDateTime`

The [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class represent a date-time without time zone. Use those for the first piece.

Your format is close to standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, just replace the SPACE with a `T`.

```
String input = "2012-06-25 15:02:22.948";
String inputStandardized = input.replace( " " , "T" );
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( inputStandardized );
```

### Offset from UTC

The other piece is the [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). We use the [`ZoneOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) class for this.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of( "+0530" );
```

Without an offset or time zone the `LocalDateTime` is *not* an actual moment on the timeline but rather a rough idea about a possible moment. Now we add your [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) to mark an actual moment, represented by the [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( ldt , offset );
```

### Zoned

A time zone is an offset *plus* rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). So better to use a time zone than a mere offset.

For example, if the context of this data is known to be [time in India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_India), use a time zone such as [`Asia/Kolkata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Kolkata) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( zoneId );
```