# What is the Android/Java equivalent of the iOS call [NSDate timeIntervalSinceNow]?

Tags: java, android, iphone, ios, date

Here is some sample code from iOS:

```
NSDate *startDateX = [NSDate date];

// Do a bunch of stuff

NSLog(@"Time difference: %f", -[startDateX timeIntervalSinceNow]);
```

The output looks like this:

```
Time difference: 15.009682
```

What is the equivalent way to do this in Android/Java?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927856/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) to calculate milliseconds:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
// Do stuff
long difference = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
Log.v("Time difference:", String.valueOf(difference));
```

If you want something more precise use [`System.nanoTime()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29). If you want seconds simply divide `System.currentTimeMillis()` by 1000.

There is the DateUtils class (`android.text.format.DateUtils`) that can calculate relative time differences like "5 mins ago". Also [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is a great 3rd party library if you plan to do a lot of work with time.

Answer (score 0):

**Java**

```
void test() {

    Date startDateX = new Date();  // represents down to milliseconds
    
    // Do a bunch of stuff
    // ...

    System.out.printf("%.3f", timeIntervalSinceNow(startDateX));

}

private Double timeIntervalSinceNow(Date date) { return 0.001 * (date.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis()); }  // The time interval between the date and the current date and time. If the date parameter is earlier than the current date and time, this property's value is negative.
```

Is equivalent to...

**Objective-C**

```
- (void) test {
    
    NSDate *startDateX = [NSDate date];
    
    // Do a bunch of stuff
    // ...

    NSLog(@"Time difference: %f", -[startDateX timeIntervalSinceNow]);
}
```

Or...
**Swift 5**

```
func test() {
    
    let startDateX = Date()
    
    // Do a bunch of stuff
    // ...

    print(String(format: "Time difference: %f", -startDateX.timeIntervalSinceNow))
}
```