# Difference between two dates including all parts and output can be in fraction

Tags: java, date

Hi I need to calculate the difference between two dates and output can be one of these -- days or months or years and the output calculates all part so it can be in fraction also.

e.g:

24.03.15-14.04.15 (in days)=-21

24.03.15-14.04.15 (in months)=-0.75

24.03.15-14.04.15 (in years)=-1/12

Not able to calculate this.

Please explain it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate time difference in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927856/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-java)

Comment: This is not duplicate. its totally different.

Comment: Have a look at [@Fizer Khan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20811441/3318377). Isn't it what you need?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating the Difference Between Two Java Date Instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

```
LocalDate d1 = new LocalDate(2015, 3, 15);
LocalDate d2 = new LocalDate(2015, 4, 14);
int days = Days.daysBetween(d1, d2).getDays();
```

Comment: confusion, is it includes all parts- years,months in it. like- 24.03.2011-14.06.2014 = should be total no. of days differences if needs day only