# how to calculate time duration with the times are String

Tags: java

I really need your help, I am working on a project for an airport. I need to calculate the duration of the longest flight(in minutes). What I do have is Departure time and arrival time which are both in String. I have not done anything yet because I am clueless as to what I must do.

Comment: First: convert those departure and arrival times into a more suitable type. Which version of Java are you using? Your urgency is irrelevant to the question, by the way...

Comment: If you want us to help you, you should give us at least two example times.

Comment: Note that in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927856/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-java the answers are (implicitly) considering that both dates are in the same timezone.

Answer (score 1):

You shall use the class `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` to parse your string into a `java.util.Date` object. With the method:

```
public Date parse(String source) throws ParseException
```

At the creation of the format, you will specify the pattern your time/date text has. FYI, it will be important to consider the timezone. If your input strings contains it: perfect. If not, be sure to take it into account.

Once you have your `Date` object, extract its time with the `getTime()` method. It will return a `long` value with the milliseconds from 1970 in GMT timezone.

If you get this `long` value for both your departure and arrival time, the difference will tell you the number of milliseconds of the trip.