# Calculating Time and Date difference

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am currently writing a report to calculate the `TotalTimeDifference` between two date variables in ***iReport***.

The two variables that I am comparing are `MO_DATECREATED` and `MO_DATECOMPLETED` and I am trying to calculate the ***time*** difference only.

I have tried setting up a variable that does a simple subtraction of the two variables- and of course that has not worked at all.

I will attach photoes of what I currently have but I am looking for the way to compare the two variables (which contains date/time) and printing out a variables with the difference in time.

Example: If the MO was `started at 1/2/15 12:55pm` and `completed at 1/3/15 1:55pm` i want to print the time difference, or how long it took, as `25 hours`

How can I do this in iReport? Thank you for helping out a newbie!

[image: My problem] [image: MyReport]

**EDIT** After answer, I would like to the show days to:

Comment: What class are the fields MO_DATECRE and MO_DATECOMP? java.lang.Date or java.lang.String??

Comment: At the moment the Expression Class is **java.lang.String**

Comment: Ok will post you an answer... why not Date????

Comment: Im unsure as to why it is not Date. I simply dropped a Text Field down and passed it the table value **MO_DATECREATED**

Comment: I can always use the drop down box in iReport and chance the expression class to Date

Comment: I post both so you understand how to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need variables for this, use directly the `textFieldExpression`

If the fields `MO_DATECREATED` and `MO_DATECOMPLETED` are declared:

**as `java.lang.Date`**

```
<field name="MO_DATECREATED" class="java.lang.Date">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

The `textFieldExpression` would be `($F{MO_DATECOMPLETED}.getTime()-$F{MO_DATECREATED}.getTime())/(1000*60*60) + " hours"`.

Hey thats [java](/questions/tagged/java) exactly so to understand what it does check out this: [How to calculate time difference in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927856/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-java)

**as `java.lang.String`**

```
<field name="MO_DATECREATED" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

We need to parse them to `Date` object's first.. your pattern is `mm/dd/yy hh:mm a`

```
(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yy hh:mm a").parse($F{MO_DATECOMPLETED}).getTime()-new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yy hh:mm a").parse($F{MO_DATECREATED}).getTime())/(1000*60*60) + " hours"
```

Considering that they maybe `null` we better add a `printWhenExpression` as well

**Complete result**

```
<textField>
     <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="eac93a84-7901-4205-b09c-556d48dc05e1">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new java.lang.Boolean($F{MO_DATECREATED}!=null && $F{MO_DATECOMPLETED}!=null)]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yy hh:mm a").parse($F{MO_DATECOMPLETED}).getTime()-new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yy hh:mm a").parse($F{MO_DATECREATED}).getTime())/(1000*60*60) + " hours"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

No doubt that it is better that they are `java.lang.Date` object, both the report will fill faster, no risk for parsing error and you can export correctly to excel ecc. To format a `java.lang.Date` object as you wish just use the pattern property.

**EDIT:** Users has opted for the `java.util.Date` and asked how he can display also minutes, for this I have created a general question on [How to create a single expression displaying time difference between two Date's as years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665069/how-to-create-a-single-expression-displaying-time-difference-between-two-dates) and it is now [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37579395/292302)

This was the temporary solution

```
<textField>
     <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="eac93a84-7901-4205-b09c-556d48dc05e1">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new java.lang.Boolean($F{MO_DATECREATED}!=null && $F{MO_DATECOMPLETED}!=null)]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{MO_DATECOMPLETED}.getTime()-$F{MO_DATECREATED}.getTime()) / (24* 60 * 60 * 1000)  + " days " +($F{MO_DATECOMPLETED}.getTime()-$F{MO_DATECREATED}.getTime()) / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24 + " hours " +  ($F{MO_DATECOMPLETED}.getTime()-$F{MO_DATECREATED}.getTime()) / (60 * 1000) % 60 + " minutes"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: How do i get this to show me the hours and minutes as well?

Comment: It is in java.lang.Date formate and your java statements works! But it only shows hours- what's the math to display the hours and minutes?

Comment: I am still having an issue of having it display the hours and minutes- thank you Petter!

Comment: Ok lets try it... : ) are you using java8?

Comment: Yes and I am using iReport to write my reports :/

Comment: I posted a question on the java section http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665069/how-to-create-a-single-expression-displaying-time-difference-between-two-dates, If no good answer comes in 10 minutes I will pass you some code to just display HH:mm

Comment: Ok I edit the answer to give you temporary answer on how to display hours and minutes... keep track of the question above... and maybe you will get a general answer on how to display these time differences...

Comment: Thank you for the help! But before it was pulling all the hours but now is not coparing the days as hours :/

Comment: I dont need days exactly but it'd be nice. The first code you posted gave me all of the hours like "123 hours" but now it only shows the difference in the time- not the date. So yes is there a way to get the difference in the days as well? It doesn't seem to be pulling the date information

Comment: I am going to post a picture

Comment: Where is it? I dont see it :3

Comment: Petter- is there a way I can calculate the average of all of the times posted in iReport?

Comment: Yes create a variable set expression of what you like to calc and use type avgerage

Comment: Petter the type average does not seem to work with your hard coded equation to find the days, hour and minutes. Any suggestions?

Comment: I did and it only displays the very last value in the Time column

Comment: okay and could you maybe look at the new question i posted as well? I appreciate all of the help you have done for me!

Comment: @Ashton see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37579395/5292302) by Tunaki it very nice.