# How to create a single expression displaying time difference between two Date's as years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds

Tags: java, date, jasper-reports

How can I create a **single** jasper report [JRExpression](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExpression.html) that visualize the difference between two `java.util.Date` in format yy year(s) month(s) dd day(s), hh hour(s), mm minute(s),  ss second(s)

```
java.util.Date startDate
java.util.Date endDate
```

A JRExpression is a single line where variable declaration is not allowed, however you may use conditional statements using syntax `boolean ? yes:no`, for you who are not familiar imagine one line of `System.out.println();`

Example of desired output (if you have a nice solution remove description of unit when not present and consider singular/plural but this is not necessary if it's a serie of if statements):

> 2 years, 8 months, 12 days, 2 hours, 53 minutes, 10 s
>
> 1 hour, 1 minute
>
> both Feb 2- Mar 4 and Mar 4 - April 6  are "1 month,  2 days",
>   daylight savings however can be ignored - thanks @Affe

Additional requirements:

- Only jasper report [dependencies](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.1.0) may be used (joda is not
  included).
- Preferable jdk 1.7 or less (1.8 is accepted if this is only solution)

There is no need to format the answer as jasper report expression it can be a simple `System.out.println` code (I'm happy to edit your answer later to also add the jasper report expression code). Example

```
((endDate.getTime()-startDate.getTime()) / (60 * 60 * 1000)) % 24 + " hour(s), " +  
((endDate.getTime()-startDate.getTime()) / (60 * 1000)) % 60 + " minute(s)"
```

What have I tried:

*I answer multiple question in the jasper report section of SO, and this question is common in report generation. I would prefer a good answer from the java section that I can link rather then passing my code on this issue (that I would only know to solve partially as example)*

This is an example on question in [jasper-report](/questions/tagged/jasper-report): [Calculating Time and Date difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34661493/calculating-time-and-date-difference-in-ireport/)

Some reference code:

[Calculate date/time difference in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351483/calculate-date-time-difference-in-java)

[How to find the duration of difference between two dates in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940200/how-to-find-the-duration-of-difference-between-two-dates-in-java)

*For you that are familiar to jasper report I don't want to use the variable declaration since this would invalidate the solution if user need to use it on parameters.*

Comment: Tangentially how do you define a month there?  Are both Feb 2- Mar 4 and Mar 4 - April 6 "One Month Two Days"?

Comment: Nice comment, I would prefer a solution like that, seems correct, this is what a client/user would expect

Comment: I don't see how you can achieve this in one line, simply because the JDK versions of the required APIs do not use a 'Fluent' style that allows them to be utilized in a one-line fashion.  Can't you just put the code in a static method and drop the class file in the /lib folder on the jasper server?

Comment: @Affe No if user (poster on so) need's to install additional libraries in ireport, jasper studio ecc this will start a never ending comment thread ... but I have feeling you can... note you can do new GregorianCalendar ecc how many time you like and I had a vague hope that someone knows about the commons library already include, no method inside of these??

Comment: Note, after @Affe comment I have lowered the requirements 1.8 is allowed, if this is only solution.

Comment: The problem with the Calendar API is you can't even do simple naive things like `new GregorianCalendar(starDate).add(DAYS, (endDate-startDate/(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)).get(MONTH)` (ignoring potential issues that has with daylight savings) because the return type of `add` is `void` not `Calendar` so you need a second "line" of code to do `get(MONTH)` on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Calendar API cannot be directly be used for this problem: every operation would require multiple lines since the interesting methods are `void` returning and can't be chained.

This is a very big stretch, but, as listed in [the dependencies of JasperReports](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.1.0), there is [`org.codehaus.castor:castor-xml:1.3.3`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.castor/castor-xml/1.3.3) which depends itself on [`commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6). We therefore can make use of the [`DurationFormatUtils.formatPeriod(startMillis, endMillis, format)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DurationFormatUtils.html#formatPeriod%28long,%20long,%20java.lang.String%29) method, which is present in `commons-lang`. The format String to use here would be

```
"y' years 'M' months 'd' days 'H' hours 'm' minutes 's' seconds'"
```

which would print the wanted String. Care must still be taken: this will include 0s (like `"0 months"`) and will also have incorrect pluralization (like `"1 months"`).

- We can use the regular expression `"(?<!\\d)0 (\\w+) ?"` to remove all the 0s for the String. This regex matches any 0, [not preceded by a digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306202/regex-for-matching-something-if-it-is-not-preceded-by-something-else) (we don't want to match 10 for example), followed by one or more word characters and optionally followed by a space.
- Then, we can use the regular expression `"(?<!\\d)1 (\\w+)s"` to match every occurence of `"1 ...s"` and replace it with `"1 ..."` to have proper pluralization. This regular expression matches any 1, not preceded by a digit, followed by one or more word characters (captured in a group) ending with an `s`; it would be replaced with `"1 $1"`, i.e. 1 followed by the value captured.

Example:

```
System.out.println(
    org.apache.commons.lang.time.DurationFormatUtils.formatPeriod(
            startDate.getTime(), 
            endDate.getTime(), 
            "y' years 'M' months 'd' days 'H' hours 'm' minutes 's' seconds'"
    )
    .replaceAll("(?<!\\d)0 (\\w+) ?", "")
    .replaceAll("(?<!\\d)1 (\\w+)s", "1 $1")
);
```

All this can be done with Java 7 or lower.

In a JasperReports, this would be an example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.1 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports jasperreports.sourceforge.net/…" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="f067f2c4-395f-4669-9fda-4fe81cc59227">
  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
  <parameter name="dateStart" class="java.util.Date" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date(1)]]></defaultValueExpression>
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="dateEnd" class="java.util.Date" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></defaultValueExpression>
  </parameter>
  <queryString><![CDATA[]]></queryString>
  <title>
    <band height="43" splitType="Stretch">
      <textField>
        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="560" height="30" uuid="cc03531c-2983-4f9a-9619-2826ed92760e"/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[org.apache.commons.lang.time.DurationFormatUtils.formatPeriod($P{dateStart}.getTime(),$P{dateEnd}.getTime(),"y' years 'M' months 'd' days 'H' hours 'm' minutes 's' seconds'").replaceAll("(?<!\\d)0 (\\w+) ?", "").replaceAll("(?<!\\d)1 (\\w+)s", "1 $1")]]></textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
    </band>
  </title>
</jasperReport>
```

With the output being:

[image]

---

If the above looks too fragile (because of the explicit dependency towards `commons-lang` that could not be there for all JasperReports version), [there is another possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25760725/1743880) using the [Java Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) introduced in Java 8.

This is *horrible* (I don't think there is a simpler way), but the output is exactly the same as above, where `start` and `end` are both [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) objects:

```
System.out.println((
    ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end) + " years " +
    ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)), end) + " months " +
    ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)).plusMonths(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)), end)), end) + " days " +
    ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)).plusMonths(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)), end)).plusDays(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)).plusMonths(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)), end)), end)), end) + " hours " +
    ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)).plusMonths(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)), end)).plusDays(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)).plusMonths(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)), end)), end)).plusHours(ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)).plusMonths(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)), end)).plusDays(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)).plusMonths(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)), end)), end)), end)), end) + " minutes " +
    ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)).plusMonths(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)), end)).plusDays(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)).plusMonths(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)), end)), end)).plusHours(ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)).plusMonths(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)), end)).plusDays(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)).plusMonths(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)), end)), end)), end)).plusMinutes(ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)).plusMonths(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)), end)).plusDays(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)).plusMonths(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)), end)), end)).plusHours(ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)).plusMonths(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)), end)).plusDays(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)).plusMonths(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start.plusYears(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(start, end)), end)), end)), end)), end)), end) + " seconds"
    )
    .replaceAll("(?<!\\d)0 (\\w+) ?", "")
    .replaceAll("(?<!\\d)1 (\\w+)s", "1 $1")
);
```