# Formula For Calculating Difference in Time

Tags: java, formula

I have two times in hours and minutes.

```
time[0]: hour1
time[1]: minutes1
time[2]: hour2
time[3]: minutes2
```

I've created this formula to calculate the difference in time in minutes:

```
((time[2] % 12 - time[0] % 12) * 60) + (time[3] - time[1])
```

I was wondering if there are any edge cases to this. In addition, what is the paradigm you would follow to create this formula (although it is very basic)?

Comment: Your algorithm is incorrect.  What do you get if `hour1` is 9 and `hour2` is 23 (assume `minutes1` and `minutes2` are zero)?

Answer (score 0):

You could express your times with the `Date` class instead, then calculate the difference and then express it in the time unit of your choice.

With this method, you will avoid a lot of tricky cases (difference between two times on two different days, time change, etc.).

I recommend you the reading of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances/10650881#10650881) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927856/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-java) but there are many answers to this same exact question on StackOverflow ;)

Note: before using `Date`, have a look to this excellent post: [What's wrong with Java Date & Time API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969651/4862968)

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes days are 24 hours long. Not all days are 24-hours long. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) mean days vary in length.

Also, we have classes already built for this. No need to roll your own. The `LocalTime` class represents a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone. A [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) represents a span of time not attached to the timeline.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.of( 8 , 0 ) ;
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.of( 14 , 0 ) ;

Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop );
long minutes = d.toMinutes() ;  // Entire duration as a total number of minutes.
```

That code too pretends that days are 24 hours long.

For realistic spans of time, use the `ZonedDateTime` class to include a date and time zone along with your time-of-day.