# How to substract 2 hours

Tags: java, android, date

I would like to to substract hour that is displayed in `textview1` from hour that is displayed in `textview2`. Im setting the hour in `textview` by pressing buttons

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US).format(new Date());
            textView.setText(sdf);
            button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US).format(new Date());
            textView2.setText(sdf);
            button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

now after clicking `button2` i also want to substract hours and set result of substraction in `textview3`. I tried to get TextViews value and put it to strings, but i guess that's not the correct way to do this. If you guys could show me how to do this, please.

Comment: Did you consider using java.time package instead of java.util.Date?

Comment: Please for your own best search before asking. You will find a good answer much faster that way. This question has been asked and answered several times, so if you don’t like the link I provided, just find a better one.

Comment: Try going through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1555262/5772683). Make sure you do some search on SO as you'll get to an answer quickly that way

Comment: What is the desired result if the result of the subtraction is negative? Either because the times have been set in backward order or because midnight has been passed?

Comment: I figure that what you really need is a `Duration`. See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34541535/5772882).

Comment: The option with midnight, and negative result will never happend because app will work only between 7:00 - 17:00

Comment: @OleV.V.  This solution is good but my project must be api lvl 18min.

Comment: @Shizzle, check if you can use ThreeTenABP, the Android Backport of the modern Java date and time API that includes `Duration`. I think you can at level 18. Much more in [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: If this is about Android, add that tag.

Comment: @OleV.V. I tried to use ThreeTenABP, like that: `Instant start = Instant.now()` then, want to put `start` value in textview by `textview.setText(start)` and there's an error "cannot resolve method (org.threeten.bt.Instant)" how can i solve this? Do i even good understand this Instant thing? this gets value from current system time?

Comment: It seems from what you are telling me that you are basically doing things correctly, so it’s hard to tell what detail is wrong. `Instant.now()` gets its values from the system clock, yes. There’s a p, not a t in `org.threeten.**bp**.Instant`, but that was probably just a typo in the comment.

Comment: Yes, it was typo.

Comment: I tried the same thing with Joda-Time, same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the new Java 8 (and 9) libraries.

For illustration, see the method below, doing this pretty simply. You can construct a correct `DateTimeFormatter` for your exact purposes, but I utilise the standard `ISO_TIME` one for illustration.

```
public static LocalTime subtract2Hours(String timeString) {
    return LocalTime.parse(timeString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME).minusHours(2);
}
```

You can format a `LocalTime` to `String` using `LocalTime.format(DateTimeFormatter)`, of which `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME` is an example. Simply then provide that `String` back.

If you were to do the type conversions in one step, you could change the method signature. But if you're only going to use it once, you could probably in-line it all into one long chain using your IDE.

Comment: Seems that the OP is doing Android development, so Java 8 Time API can't be used directly yet. This solution will work using [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Comment: Oh, then perhaps try `DateUtils.addHours(date, -2)` from `org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils`

Comment: OR, based on the Source there, `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); c.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM").parse(timeString)); c.add(Calendar.HOUR, -2); return c.getTime();`