# How to manipulate Ranges of Time of a Day

Tags: java, intervals, localtime

I'm working with an agenda in Java. I have stored in my database the day of the week, the start and end time of some labs availability.

Now I need to provide a service for a schedule system by showing only the unavailable times of the day. For example, if day one has start time 13:00 and end time 19:00, I need to return a range just like this:
[00:00 - 13:00, 19:00 - 23:59] . Remembering that a day can have more than a range available.

Is there any Java Class or API that could help me on subtracting these ranges?

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927856/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-java

Comment: Yep, you can use [Duration or Period](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My lib [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) offers following solution for the subtraction problem:

```
ClockInterval fullDay = ClockInterval.between(PlainTime.of(0), PlainTime.of(24));
ClockInterval slot = ClockInterval.between(PlainTime.of(13, 0), PlainTime.of(19, 0));

IntervalCollection<PlainTime> icoll = IntervalCollection.onClockAxis().plus(fullDay);
List<ChronoInterval<PlainTime>> result = icoll.minus(slot).getIntervals();
```

The resulting list of half-open intervals (with open end) can be easily iterated through and gives the expected result {[T00:00/T13:00), [T19:00/T24:00)}. Every result interval can be [converted](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/ClockInterval.html#from-net.time4j.range.ChronoInterval-) to a standard `ClockInterval`, too. There are also various methods to print such intervals in a localized way. Furthermore, you might find the class `DayPartitionBuilder` interesting which allows to connect weekdays and time schedules in streaming, see the example given in the [documentation](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/DayPartitionBuilder.html).

About compatibility with `java.time`:

- The between()-methods of `ClockInterval` also accept instances of `java.time.LocalTime`.
- Every instance of `PlainTime` can be converted back to `LocalTime` by help of the method `toTemporalAccessor()` with the exception of the value 24:00 which exists in Time4J but not in `java.time.LocalTime`.

Comment: Hey bro, thanks for the tip. You did an amazing job with this lib, very powerful and very well designed. Really incredible, you are the man! I just solved my problem in few minutes...

Comment: @Andre Thank you. Your post makes me thinking about possible future enhancements, too, for example a constant for "full day" in `ClockInterval` and an extra minus()-method for simple cases as convenience.