# How to subtract two time values?

Tags: java

I have two time STRING values :

```
First : 1:12.203
Second : 1:04.009
```

Milliseconds come after '.'

How can I receive the subtraction of this two values?
I need to have 0:08.194 or something like this.

I don't know which variables to use and how it realize, so I'll be glad for your help and properly piece of code.

Comment: Do you have the strings `"1:12.203"` and `"1:04.009"` as input?

Comment: Without telling us in what kind of data structure you have those 2 values it is literally impossible to provide an answer. Are those just 2 Strings/Text or some kind of java.time objects?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, Strings

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Strings

Comment: Start with converting your strings to `Date` or another appropriate type.

Comment: @mustaccio `Date` has not been an appropriate type since the `java.time` package appeared in Java 8. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4927884/5622596

Imports needed:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
```

Code that prints out the time : **00:08.194**

```
    String first =  "1:12.203";
    String second = "1:04.009";

    SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss.SSS");

    try {
        Date dateStart = formater.parse(first);
        Date dateEnd = formater.parse(second);

        long milliSeconds = dateStart.getTime() - dateEnd.getTime(); 

        Date timeDiff = new Date(milliSeconds);

        System.out.println(formater.format(timeDiff));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If you are looking for a method to return a string.Try something like this:

```
@Test
public void printDiff() {
    String first = "1:12.203";
    String second = "1:04.009";

    try {
        System.out.println(getTimeDiffString(first, second));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String getTimeDiffString(String first, String second) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss.SSS");

    //Get number of milliseconds between times: 
    Date dateStart = formater.parse(first);
    Date dateEnd = formater.parse(second);
    long milliSeconds = dateStart.getTime() - dateEnd.getTime();

    //Convert time difference to mm:ss.SSS string
    Date timeDiff = new Date(milliSeconds);
    return formater.format(timeDiff).toString();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) to store these things. There is no nice declarative way to parse your custom format, but you can do so quite easily using a regular expression.

```
private static Duration parseDuration(String duration)
{
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+):(\\d{2})\\.(\\d{3})");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(duration);

    if (matcher.matches())
    {
        long mins = Long.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
        long secs = Long.valueOf(matcher.group(2));
        long millis = Long.valueOf(matcher.group(3));

        return Duration.ofMinutes(mins).plusSeconds(secs).plusMillis(millis);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid duration " + duration);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
Duration diff = parseDuration("1:12.203").minus(parseDuration("1:04.009"));
```

If you want to format the difference nicely using the same format, see [How to format a duration in java? (e.g format H:MM:SS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266825/how-to-format-a-duration-in-java-e-g-format-hmmss)

Comment: But how to print it via Sysout?
I received "PT8.194S", is It properly?