# How to get time difference/duration in hour and minute along with in java?

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

In my project, I need to find duration of staying outside in office time of an employee from goToVisitTime and returnTime. The main concerning point is  goToVisitTime and returnTime both are date (java.util) type [getting from other method, can't change anymore] and styingOutSideTime also must be date (java.util) type. For example:

```
Date goTOvisitTime = "12:25";
Date returnTime = "14:19";
```

So, output should be like,

```
styingOutSideTime = "01:54";
```

Therefore my method looks like below:

```
public Date getDiffTime(Date goTOvisitTime, Date returnTime) {

//calculate difference 

return styingOutSideTime;
}
```

I have spent lots of time to determine the solution. I tried to use almost all of Date and Time from Java and Joda Time as well. Additionally, I went through the following links

[How to calculate time difference in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927856/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-java)

[Java how to calculate time differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810023/java-how-to-calculate-time-differences/3810425#3810425)

[Convert seconds value to hours minutes seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118922/convert-seconds-value-to-hours-minutes-seconds)

[How to get hour/minute difference in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924022/how-to-get-hour-minute-difference-in-java)

However, almost all of the solutions are either parameter or return value is a string. additionally, returning either hour or minute only.

Comment: How the difference between the two dates will be a date is possible? So, your method `getDiffTime` should not return Date.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem that how I can return value "hh: mm" format and it would be treated as Date type whereas we can format Date as "hh: mm" format. --@AmitBera

Comment: Just return the String in the format `hh:mm`

Comment: As far as I can see, it’s in [this answer to the last question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39553805/5772882).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalTime` and `Duration`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the duration should not be a `Date`, it should be a [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html).

If you only want to the hour part and the minute part, you can do it like this:

```
Duration duration = Duration.between(goTOvisitTime.toInstant(), returnTime.toInstant());

int hours = duration.toHoursPart();
int minutes = duration.toMinutesPart();

String formattedDuration =  String.format("%02d:%02d", hours, minutes);
```

Comment: Simpler: `goTOvisitTime.toInstant()`. New conversion methods were added to the old classes.

Comment: Instead of `toHours` and `toMinutes`, in Java 9 and later use `toHoursPart` and `toMinutesPart`.